# How to decode ion_binary of Amazon QLDB in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-qldb

I was playing with **QLDB** of Amazon with ruby and used the **aws-sdk-qldb** and **aws-sdk-qldbsession** gem. I was getting result as IonBinary. But not able to decode and parse it.

Following is the code

```
      cred = Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'])

      qldb_session_client = Aws::QLDBSession::Client.new(region: 'ap-southeast-1', credentials: cred)

      start_session_req = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::StartSessionRequest.new
      start_session_req.ledger_name = 'ledger-test'


      command_request = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::SendCommandRequest.new

      command_request.start_session = start_session_req

      resp = qldb_session_client.send_command(command_request)
      session_token = resp.start_session.session_token

      command_request = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::SendCommandRequest.new
      command_request.session_token = session_token
      command_request.start_transaction = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::StartTransactionRequest.new
      resp = qldb_session_client.send_command(command_request)
      transaction_id = resp.start_transaction.transaction_id

      command_request = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::SendCommandRequest.new
      command_request.session_token = session_token
      command_request.execute_statement = Aws::QLDBSession::Types::ExecuteStatementRequest.new
      command_request.execute_statement.transaction_id = transaction_id
      command_request.execute_statement.statement = 'select * from testing'

      resp = qldb_session_client.send_command(command_request)
```

now if I use the following code

```
resp.execute_statement.first_page.values[0]
```

I get

```
{:ion_binary=>"\xE0\x01\x00\xEA\xEE\x9A\x81\x83\xDE\x96\x87\xBE\x93\x89firstname\x88lastname\xDE\x9D\x8A\x8Dtesting first\x8B\x8Ctesting last", :ion_text=>"[FILTERED]"}
```

I am not able to decode this ion_binary using binary parser.

Comment: Decode to _what_? It’s a perfectly valid binary.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin thanks for the msg. this binary contains string in between. it should return firstname: testing first
lastname: testing last 
this one is AWS ION Binary([ http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/docs/binary.html]) . I have used various unpack options to unpack this one. but not working properly. then we have to parse it. ion_text should also return the plain text but in this case its returning nil as well. 

`{ firstname: 'testing first', last name: 'testing last' }`

Answer (score 1):

Decoding the stream is likely to be done with [`Aws::EventStream::Decoder#decode`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/EventStream/Decoder.html#decode-instance_method). That said, somewhat like below should work.

```rb
Aws::EventStream::Decoder.new.decode(
  StringIO.new(result[:ion_binary])
)
```

Comment: thanks .. I had done that before this actually raise an error `undefined method `read' for #<String:0x007fa9523face8>`

Comment: OK, it requires `IO` → wrap your string in [`StringIO`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html). I will update the answer.

Comment: @alekesei thanks . Now I am getting the enumerable , but when I am traversing through the enumerable it's returning nil. But at least I am getting enumerable.

Comment: In the link I posted it’s stated `decode` returns `Enumerable<Message>`. What do you mean “it’s returning `nil`”? What number of elements this enumerable has?

Comment: thanks for your help. mainly the problem with in the sdk gem. Enumerable<message> is nil. We have posted that one to GitHub page of sdk . they are looking into it.

Comment: I am trying to use the above, however I keep on getting a Aws::EventStream::Errors::PreludeChecksumError. Is there anything that I'm missing? Maybe this doesn't work in the latest version of the SDK?